# Greyed out Chrome Extension to be available only to the declared sites in manifest.json upon logged in else greyed out on all other sites

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, browser-extension

I need the extension to be available only when the user is logged in to the parent site i.e www.flyship.com and also to the sites which are mentioned in the manifest.json.

```
 "content_scripts": [
      {
        "matches": [
          "*://*.flyship.com/*",
          "*://app.yield.io/*",
          "*://*.indeedjobs.com/*"
        ],
        "js": ["scripts/content.js","scripts/index.js"]
      }
    ],
```

In the background.js i am checking if the user is logged in to flyship.com using this code

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse){
    if(request.login === "logged"){
      checkUser(request, sender, sendResponse);
      // checkforValidUrl();
    }
return true;
}
function checkUser(request, sender, sendResponse){
    chrome.cookies.get({url : "https://www.flyship.com/app", name: "csrftoken"}, function(cookie){
      const CSRF = cookie.value;
      sendResponse({token: CSRF});
      console.log(CSRF);
    });
  }
```

I need the extension to be greyed out on all the other sites except the mentioned sites in manifest.json that too only when the user is logged in to flyship.com.

P.S : i have tried with declarativeContent but it doesn't seem to be working for me or maybe atleast am not able to deduce it according to my needs. following is the code that iam checking the urls on

```
function checkforValidUrl(){
  chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function() {
    chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.removeRules(undefined, function() {
      chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.addRules([
        {
          conditions: [
            new chrome.declarativeContent.PageStateMatcher({
              pageUrl: { urlContains: '*://*.flyship.com/*' },
            }),
            new chrome.declarativeContent.PageStateMatcher({
              pageUrl: { urlContains: '*://app.yield.io/*' }
            }),
            new chrome.declarativeContent.PageStateMatcher({
              pageUrl: { urlContains: 'https://www.indeedjobs.com/*' }
            })
          ],
          actions: [ new chrome.declarativeContent.ShowPageAction() ]
        }
      ]);
    });
  });
}
```

I have been banging my head since 1 week to solve this problem reading docs and what not.A polite help in this regard would be very helpful.

Comment: chrome.runtime.onInstalled should be in the global scope - it runs when the extension is installed or updated. In other words, it won't invoke the callback in your case so you need to register the rules directly. Also, this shouldn't take a week to get right - it takes less than 5 minutes to read about one API function.

Comment: @wOxxOm Thanks for the reply but if you could read the question again, my problem is i need the extension to be available and not greyed out to the other 2 URL's only when the user is logged in to www.flyship.com. Also, i'm new to extension development